# Hide all application windows except a specified one on OS X

Tags: macos, productivity, focus

Is there a **free and stable** solution satisfying this kind of need and preferably having a menu bar to let the user to exclude a particular app?

Comment: Is this for when the Boss is coming? :-)

Comment: ahahahahahahahah lol :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide all applications except for the currently active one, go to the current application menu next to the Apple menu (in bold text e.g. **Chrome**) and select *Hide Others*, or ⌥⌘H.

Comment: Clicking on a dock icon with Command and Option down also effects switching applications and hiding everything else.